# Error install driver (Orico) from makefile

Tags: drivers, compiling, make

I'm trying to install the driver for an Audio Mobile Host Expansion Dock (ADS4) from Orico.

Ubuntu is not recognizing the dock so they have to be installed manually. I downloaded the linux drivers from the manufacturer's website. It contained these 4 files:

- 50-usb-realtek-net.rules
- compatibility.h
- Makefile
- r8152.c

Searching on the internet I understood that I had to run the makefile. So I did the following at the terminal:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

(Make sure I have current kernel headers installed, I saw this in a similar question )
And them

```
sudo make
```

However, I get this error

```
ricardo@ricardo-linux:~/Downloads/r8152-2.07.0$ sudo make
[sudo] password for ricardo:
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/ricardo/Downloads/r8152-2.07.0 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:107: scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Makefile:527: scripts_basic] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:704: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:17: modules] Error 2
ricardo@ricardo-linux:~/Downloads/r8152-2.07.0$
```

Needless to say, I am quite new to linux and have always used the graphical interface, so perhaps the solution is obvious

Answer (score 0):

In the end the error was obvious, gcc was not installed ("gcc: not found"). I used this guide to install it https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04/
After that I had no problem installing the driver
I'll leave it in case someone else has the problem